# Unchecked cast warning from compiler

Tags: java, swing, compiler-warnings, jlist, listselectionlistener

I am trying to create a game. It is almost ready, but I get unchecked cast warning when I try to compile it.
Here is the beginning of my code:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener {

    private Tiles tiles;
    private ConfigurationStore st;

    public GUI(ConfigurationStore cs) {
        super("My Game");
        st = cs;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1000,700);

        add(ConfigurationsPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    }
```

This is my ConfigurationsPanel():

```
    private JPanel ConfigurationsPanel() {
        JPanel conf = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        addBorder(conf, "Configurations");
        ArrayList<Configuration> configurations = new ArrayList<>();
        configurations = store.getConfigurations();
        Configuration[] configurationsArray = new Configuration[configurations.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < configurations.size(); i++) {
            configurationsArray[i] = configurations.get(i);
        }
        JList<Configuration> list = new JList<Configuration>(configurationsArray);
        list.addListSelectionListener(this);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        conf.add(scrollPane);
        return conf;
    }
```

And this is my valueChanged method:

```
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        JList<Configuration> list = (JList<Configuration>) e.getSource();
        Configuration configuration = list.getSelectedValue();
        tiles = new Tiles(c);
    }
```

Compiler gives warning in the valueChanged method where I wrote  `JList<Configuration> list = (JList<Configuration>) e.getSource();` by saying: `required: JList<Configuration> found: Object`.
Can you please tell me what part of my code is not right and how can I remove that warning.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work fine despite the warning? If so you could just suppress it with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read and understand the warning.

Acknowledge that JVM cannot protect you from bad cast, and take responsibility for knowing what you're doing.

Then suppress the warning:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    JList<Configuration> list = (JList<Configuration>) e.getSource();
    ...
```

Comment: With `@SupressWarnings("unchecked")` it now works properly. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can either `@supressWarnings("unchecked")` as Andreas answer says, or you can check it. In your case, probably suppresswarning sound better. In other cases though, it might be better to check the type:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    JList<?> list = (JList<?>) e.getSource();
    Object selectedValue = list.getSelectedValue();
    if (selectedValue instanceof Configuration)
    {
        Configuration configuration = (Configuration) selectedValue;
        tiles = new Tiles(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: While I mostly agree with this answer, getSource returns an Object and not Jlist<?> so you are not really changing the problem, better to use an object and check it's type as a JList.

Comment: @mwarren Checking if `e.getSource()` is a `JList` instance, is another thing. The warning OP gets, is because of type erasure in run time. These two matters are close, but not the same. Checking if `e.getSource()` is a `JList`, you will still have to do one more check like I did to check if the `JList` holds `<Configuration>`.

Comment: I understand that, I should have made my self clearer. I don't think there is a good way to remove the issue I was just trying to point out the assumption that source is a JList of some kind.

Comment: @mwarren Well, the best option here, is to hold the `JList` in a field and do not rely on `anyKindOfEvent.getSource()`.